# Remove all rows from a table where an invalid "URL" has been entered

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

A somewhat odd Postgresql question for our highly specific use case.  We have a table which accepts URLs as a part of a comment input from our users. This is on a highly trafficked site. We had some PHP code that was validating that users only entered correctly-formed URLs, if they included one in their comment (usually comment text does not include any URLs).

However, sadly, our PHP is old on an old server. So at some point the `ereg` logic we had became dysfunctional. Which means miscreant users have had a field day entering comments with badly formed URLs like the following:

```
l%20are%20generally%20included%20almost%20anyplace--even%20if%20your%20&quot;yard&quot;%20is%20bound%20to%20an%20outdoor%20patio%20or%20balcony.Adding%20water%20to%20your%20patio%20could%20be%20as%20simple%20as%20aiming%20a%20low%20dish%20of%20water%20designed%20for%20use%20in%20the%20form%20of%20birdbath.Any%20cursory%20container%20around%206%20in%20.wide%20and%20a%20half-inch%20deep%20will%20attempt%20to%20work.Pie%20pans,%20garbage%20can%20lids,%20or%20flo
```

Note that it's not a URL at all. Hence, our question: is there a Postgresql-only way, perhaps through some PL/SQL function or some stored function or something, that we can use to delete all these rubbish records from our database? We'd ideally not want to use a PHP program that went through the entire database and checked it against the valid URL pattern.

We'd like to execute this within PG itself. We can take the database offline to perform this task for as long as it takes.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you give an example of a correct URL and maybe another one which is again wrong?

Comment: Thank Antonis. A valid URL starts with `http` or `https` or `ftp` or `sftp`,  and then the usual URI validations. The latter bit, the usual URI stuff, is available online for PHP etc. I have not seen any stored function for pgsql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE url_column !~* '(https?|ftp)://(-\.)?([^\s/?\.#-]+\.?)+(/[^\s]*)?'
```

Try this query, validate the output en then you could create a DELETE query with this example.

Comment: Thank you, but this seems to return valid URLs, which begin with 'http://'. Maybe the regex is incorrect? But thank you for this direction, it sounds promising!

Comment: (https?|ftp) should take care of that, the ? after the http"s" means the s in https is not mandatory. Could you try it with "(http|https|ftp)" to make it more explicit? I've validated the query with PgSQL 9.1, which version are you using?

Comment: I Cannot validate this query against 9.0, but you could take a look at the docs for this operator: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE. Maybe try some other URL regexes from https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Comment: Thank you for helping out, but most of those regexps are not Postgres-friendly. I keep getting this error: `ERROR:  invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid`

Comment: The regexps are perfectly valid, you just have to take the delimiters and modifiers off. This is the first character of the string, and somewhere on the end of the string with some chars behind it. @(.+)@is should be just (.+) in the Postgres query

Comment: Thank you. That helps a lot, much appreciated. Now the issue is that some users have URLs like `www.commarts.com` (without the `http://`), which is actually OK. This is an issue, because the regex will mark this as an invalid URL, although it's actually a valid URL pattern just that the user didn't know they had to put an http! So I'm thinking: we need to (1) check the string for the presence of `http|https|ftp|sftp`, and if found then apply the regex (2) if not found, then first add an `http` at the front, and then run the regex..

Comment: If this logic makes sense, how would I do that in the regex? Or is this going to be a messy IF condition in the `where` clause?

Comment: There isn't really any sane way to do that in one query, if you would like to cover those edge cases, you could try some other regex queries to filter out / fix those records first, and then check with the full url validation regex again.